# LucaDegasperi OAuth2Server issues with Laravel 4 with composer update

Tags: git, laravel-4, oauth, xampp, composer-php

I'm quiet new to Laravel and I found it pretty good and easy mostly coming from a CodeIgniter background. But today I've just stumbled onto my first biggest issue with Laravel and it's great composer.

I have just cloned Laravel web project from GIT. Once cloned I couldn't run the app on my local XAMPP server. I though maybe it's a dependency issue, so I run composer update and here is the error I got:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
{"error":
    {
        "type":"ErrorException",
        "message":"Declaration of LucaDegasperi\\OAuth2Server\\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider::boot() should be compatible with Illuminate\\Support\\ServiceProvider::boot()",
        "file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\working_folder\\myproject\\vendor\\lucadegasperi\\oauth2-        server-laravel\\src\\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider.php",
        "line":177
    }
}
{"error":
   {
        "type":"ErrorException",
        "message":"Declaration of LucaDegasperi\\OAuth2Server\\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider::boot() should be compatible with Illuminate\\Support\\ServiceProvider::boot()",
        "file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\working_folder\\myproject\\vendor\\lucadegasperi\\oauth2-server-laravel\\src\\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider.php",
        "line":177
    }
}
```

I have researched for solutions on-line but I had no chance fixing it. Here is few things I have tried:

- changed the  version of the package lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel
- change the minimum-stability for dev to stable and vice versa

All attempts of fixing resulted in other errors.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem here and if so what can I do to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after all. Got some help in the [Laravel Chat Room](http://laravel.io/chat). 
Basically I had to change my oAuth2server version, in the composer.json file from **"dev-master"** to 
 **"~1.0.0"**. This appears to work fine with ***Laravel 4.2***.
So if you have the same issue  just try changing the version and see if you have any luck with that.

Otherwise I would really recommend asking your question in the **[Laravel Chat Room](http://laravel.io/chat)** people are really helpful there. I got my response a minute after asking.